# How to convert 2d slice of interface into struct

Tags: go

I want to get all the rows from the Google sheets API. It returns the data with the [type](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/api/sheets/v4#DataFilterValueRange)
`[][]interface{}`.

My struct is

```
type Record struct {
    Name string `json:"firstname"`
    Mobile    string `json:"mobile"`
}
```

I would like to put all the rows in a slice of struct `[]Record` where each field is a cell in the excel sheet.

Please see the code below for my attempt:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)
func main() {
    srv err := InitialiseSheets()
    fmt.Println("")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to retrieve data from sheet: %v", err)
    }

    spreadsheetId := "1VoMAKHSnB6nptPnQqabMlKWraxWolYgPBxRo-thwmgk"
    readRange := "A:B"
    resp, err := srv.Spreadsheets.Values.Get(spreadsheetId, readRange).Do()

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to retrieve data from sheet: %v", err)
    }

    var records []Record = make([]Record, len(resp.Values))

    byt, err := resp.MarshalJSON()
    var dat map[string]interface{}

    if err = json.Unmarshal(byt, &dat); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    for key, value := range dat {
        switch key {
        case "values":
            switch vv := value.(type) {
            case []interface{}:
                for i, u := range vv {
                    switch r := u.(type) {
                    case interface{}:
            records[i].Name = r.([]interface{})[0].(string)
                        records[i].Mobile = r.([]interface{})[1].(string)
                        // [Daniel Webster 425255565]
                        fmt.Println("kk.([]interface{})", r.([]interface{}))
                        // [Daniel Webster]
                        fmt.Println("kk.([]interface{})[0]", r.([]interface{})[0])

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm sure doing something like `records[i].Mobile = r.([]interface{})[1].(string)` isn't a proper way to do it, not sure how I even came up with it. Whats the best way in Go to do what I'm trying to achieve?

If you would like to run this code please setup authentication first by following: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/go and you can copy/paste my code.

Comment: What does the returned data look like? Whatever is returned by `resp.MarshalJSON()`

Comment: @Ibu it returns a slice of byte. specifically https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/api/sheets/v4#ValueRange.MarshalJSON

Comment: you can do something like `fmt.Printf("%s",string(byt))` to see the actual content, so you can properly used the returned data rather use the interface.

Comment: In order to correctly understand about your situation, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet?

Comment: @Tanaike Hey, this is the one i'm using: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VoMAKHSnB6nptPnQqabMlKWraxWolYgPBxRo-thwmgk/edit#gid=0

Comment: @Ibu wow, thanks. The returned string is 
""{"majorDimension":"ROWS","range":"Sheet1!A1:F1000","values":[["Daniel Webster","425255565"],["Omar Roger","425566544"],["Samuel Peter","455551515"]]}""

It is nicely formatted but how can I put it in a struct?

Comment: @tony Thank you for providing the sample Spreadsheet. For example, in your case, how about directly putting the values of ``resp.Values`` to ``records`` like ``for i, row := range resp.Values { records[i].Name = row[0].(string) records[i].Mobile = row[1].(string) }``? I'm not sure whether this is the result you want. So I posted this as a comment.

Comment: @Tanaike thanks! works well, happy to accept your answer!

Comment: @tony Thank you for replying. I posted it as an answer. Could you please confirm it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this modification? In this case, the values are directly put from `resp.Values` to `records`.

#### Modified script:

```
func main() {
    srv err := InitialiseSheets()
    fmt.Println("")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to retrieve data from sheet: %v", err)
    }

    spreadsheetId := "1VoMAKHSnB6nptPnQqabMlKWraxWolYgPBxRo-thwmgk"
    readRange := "A:B"
    resp, err := srv.Spreadsheets.Values.Get(spreadsheetId, readRange).Do()

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to retrieve data from sheet: %v", err)
    }

    var records []Record = make([]Record, len(resp.Values))

    // Below script was modified.
    for i, row := range resp.Values {
        records[i].Name = row[0].(string)
        records[i].Mobile = row[1].(string)
    }

    // do something

}
```